# How to skip the Windows 8 lock screen image?

Tags: windows, windows-8, lock-screen

Every time I start up the pc or lock it manually and I want to log in again, I have to press random button or mouse click to remove the "Start-screen background". After that I can enter my password/pin to unlock the pc.

What I want is to just start enter the password/pin right away and be done with it. Why show a start-screen that's made for removing anyway?

So how do I skip the lock-screen image? Or make it automatically move away? Or move the password/pin box to the lock-screen? Anything will do, I just want to instantly enter my credentials and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Copy this into a new .reg file and import it with regedit.exe:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization]
"NoLockScreen"=dword:00000001
```

This disables the LockScreen completely.

Answer (score 0):

> ***EDIT:*** **Below method didn't really work well for me in the end (the "boot case" still shows the lock screen), but I'll leave it here for the record and in case someone has some idea how to improve it.**

Reportedly, the registry-based method doesn't work anymore after the Windows 10 Anniversary Update. A new method seems to be as follows:

1. *Start/Windows menu* → type `secpol.msc` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
2. In tree pane on the left, select *Software Restriction Policies* (node 6 of 9 total) → *Additional Rules*;

   - if you don't see it, select menu *Action* → *New Software Restriction Policies* to create it.
3. Right-click on the right pane (with "Name", "Security Level", etc) → *New Path Rule*;
4. In *Path*, paste: `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.LockApp_cw5n1h2txyewy`
5. Make sure that *Security Level* is set to *Disallowed*.
6. Click *Ok*.

*Source: [ghacks.net](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/08/05/disable-windows-10-lock-screen/)*